# How To Get The Current View - Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-view, android-viewbinder

I am getting NULL pointer exception currently, when I run this thread

```
public void run() {
    long idle = 0;
    this.touch();
    do {
        idle = System.currentTimeMillis() - lastUsed;
        Log.d(TAG, "Application is idle for " + idle + " ms");
        if ((idle > 5000) && (check == false)) { // Checking For 2 Minutes.
            Log.e("AthanAd", "2 minutes over - Show Ad.");
            adView = (AdView) view.findViewById(R.id.adView);
            adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
            check = true;
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(8000); // check every 5 seconds
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Waiter interrupted!");
        }
        if (idle > period) {
            idle = 0;
            // do something here - e.g. call popup or so
        }
    } while (!stop);
    Log.d(TAG, "Finishing Waiter thread");
}
```

I am getting the exception this line.

**`adView = (AdView) view.findViewById(R.id.adView);`**

At the top of the application I have declared **View view;** but I know I have not linked it to any view.

My question is: **How I can get the view visible to screen?**

Comment: use the `SetVisibility(..)` method to make a view visible

Comment: you have to initialize "view" variable using findViewById method.

Comment: How can I do this. Please give an example of what is the correct way to initialize the view in this scenerio?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not use `view.findViewById(R.id.adView);`
use `findViewById(R.id.adView);`

```
LinearLayout ln=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.yourid);
ln.addView(adView);
```

Comment: When I try to add this code, i receive an error stating "The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type ClassName". My ClassName extends by Thread. I think thats why I am getting this issue.

Comment: why you are not initializing the adView in oncreate method; and then load it again and again

Comment: I am trying to load the AdView from the thread because in thread i can easily identify the time interval that is passed.

Comment: Ya I know but you should initialize or assign the memory in onCreate() like adView = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView); then use it load new addrequest in your thread. ok :)

Comment: But still in that case I need the AdView object from activity class.